# Why is my easy "three digits, followed by three identical digits, followed by four identical digits" regex not working?

Tags: javascript, regex

I hate to post a "this should be easy, what am I missing" question, but... this should be easy, what am I missing? I'm getting no match on this test code and I cannot see why. Pattern is (or should be) "any three digits, followed by any three identical digits, followed by any four identical digits."

```js
testVar = "1231112222";
testPattern = "/\d{3}(\d)\1\1(\d)\2\2\2/"
if(testVar.match(RegExp(testPattern))) {
    console.log("match");
}
else {
    console.log("no match");
}
```

Comment: Need double escape in your regexp string or use literal `/\d{3}(\d)\1\1(\d)\2\2\2/` as regex

Comment: ah, the forward slashes at beginning and end don't fix it anyway (sorry they're missing, I'd taken them out for testing and forgotten to put them back in for my question; I will edit my question now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
testVar = "1231112222";
testPattern = /\d{3}(\d)\1\1(\d)\2\2\2/;
if(testPattern.test(testVar)) {
    console.log("match");
}
else {
    console.log("no match");
}
```